# Display an svg-circle on a polymaps

Tags: javascript, svg, bing-maps, geojson

I'm displaying a bing-map with the use of polymaps with [this code](http://vantoegevoegdewaarde.nl/maps.txt). It's a simple script derived from the bing-example on the website of polymaps.

I now want to display a marker, a svg-circle on certain coordinates. 
I've tried to use the `po.geojson("load", load)` to load the geojson feature collection and display the point in the feature collection. The structure [looks like this](http://vantoegevoegdewaarde.nl/punt.txt) (off course it should be a JSON string, but this is more easy to read.)
But the script does not display the marker.

Using this code:

```
[...]

map.add(po.geoJson()
.url("http://link/to/current.php")
.on("load", load));

[...]

function load(e) {
  for (var i = 0; i < e.features.length; i++) {
    var feature = e.features[i];
    feature.element.setAttribute("class", "punt");
  }
}
```

css:

```
.punt {
     fill: cyan;
     fill-opacity: 1;
     stroke: #012;
}
```

Won't display the blue dot on the map.

**Is there a way to display a svg-circle on the polymaps map? So that I can periodically call the construct-`function` of this circle to update the location of the svg-circle?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the circles yourself in the load function? [This example](http://polymaps.org/ex/shadow.html) shows how to add a big circle on a point of interest.